# Is there a way to parse a nested XML with attributes in its tag elements using jackson API without creating POJOs?

Tags: java, jackson, xml-parsing, pojo, jackson-dataformat-xml

I was trying to parse a nested XML where few of the nested elements have attributes. I used jackson APIs without creating the POJOs (As I would have to create 30+ POJOs to store the data from XML, so I was trying without creating POJOs), but I'm unable to get all the elements from the XML. It is only picking the last element in the XML file. When I searched for the reason, I understood it is because of the attributes in the tag elements.

Is there a way to parse the nested XML with attributes without the creation of POJOs using jackson API?

Here is the sample XML:

```
<employee>
     <id>1</id>
     <name firstname="A" secondname="B">XYZ</name
     <address>
             <homeaddress city="NY" pincode="123">33rd Street</homeaddress>
             <officeaddress city="NY" pincode="456">45th Street</officeaddress>
    </address>

     <id>2</id>
     <name firstname="P" secondname="Q">PQR</name
     <address>
             <homeaddress city="NJ" pincode="123">Grrove</homeaddress>
             <officeaddress city="NJ" pincode="456">Newark</officeaddress>
    </address>
     <id>3</id>
     <name firstname="abc" secondname="def">asd</name
     <address>
             <homeaddress city="aa" pincode="234">Downtown</homeaddress>
             <officeaddress city="aa" pincode="456">uptown</officeaddress>
    </address>
</employee>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Incremental/partial reading](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#incrementalpartial-readingwriting-24) example to read `XML` tag by tag. Solution depends from which values you want to read and which (if any) you want to skip. Also, it depends wether you can assume `XML` has "stable" format and all nodes are available in the same order and exist even for empty values. In other case you need to write more sophisticated code. For example, for below `XML` payload:

```
<employee>
    <id>1</id>
    <name firstname="A" secondname="B">XYZ</name>
    <address>
        <homeaddress city="NY" pincode="123">33rd Street</homeaddress>
        <officeaddress city="NY" pincode="456">45th Street</officeaddress>
    </address>

    <id>2</id>
    <name firstname="P" secondname="Q">PQR</name>
    <address>
        <homeaddress city="NJ" pincode="124">Grrove</homeaddress>
        <officeaddress city="LA" pincode="789">Newark</officeaddress>
    </address>
    <id>3</id>
    <name firstname="abc" secondname="def">asd</name>
    <address>
        <homeaddress city="AA" pincode="234">Downtown</homeaddress>
        <officeaddress city="AB" pincode="456">uptown</officeaddress>
    </address>
</employee>
```

Using `Jackson` in version `2.10.1` we can read above payload as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.FromXmlParser;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class XmlMapperApp {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("./resource/test.xml").getAbsoluteFile();

        XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xmlFile));

        XmlMapper mapper = XmlMapper.xmlBuilder().build();
        try (FromXmlParser parser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(reader)) {
            while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
                String id = readNext(parser, "id");
                if (id == null) {
                    break;
                }
                String firstName = readNext(parser, "firstname");
                String secondName = readNext(parser, "secondname");
                String name = readNextValue(parser);
                System.out.printf("ID='%s', NAME='%s %s %s'\n", id, firstName, secondName, name);

                String city = readNext(parser, "city");
                String pinCode = readNext(parser, "pincode");
                String homeAddress = readNextValue(parser);
                System.out.printf("Home Address = '%s, %s %s'\n", city, pinCode, homeAddress);

                city = readNext(parser, "city");
                pinCode = readNext(parser, "pincode");
                homeAddress = readNextValue(parser);
                System.out.printf("Office Address = '%s, %s %s'\n\n", city, pinCode, homeAddress);
            }
        }
    }

    private static String readNext(FromXmlParser parser, String name) throws IOException {
        JsonToken token;
        while ((token = parser.nextToken()) != null) {
            switch (token) {
                case FIELD_NAME:
                    String currentName = parser.currentName();
                    if (name.equals(currentName)) {
                        parser.nextToken();
                        return parser.getValueAsString();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String readNextValue(FromXmlParser parser) throws IOException {
        JsonToken token;
        while ((token = parser.nextToken()) != null) {
            switch (token) {
                case VALUE_STRING:
                    return parser.getValueAsString();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
ID='1', NAME='A B XYZ'
Home Address = 'NY, 123 33rd Street'
Office Address = 'NY, 456 45th Street'

ID='2', NAME='P Q PQR'
Home Address = 'NJ, 124 Grrove'
Office Address = 'LA, 789 Newark'

ID='3', NAME='abc def asd'
Home Address = 'AA, 234 Downtown'
Office Address = 'AB, 456 uptown'
```